# Missuse of AWS Lambda by using it for IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, rds, bigdata

I'm thinking about using AWS Lambda instead an EC2 Instance for handling around ~4M requests per month. I have a lot of IoT Devices which are sending every minute a couple of data (8M records daily) currently to my EC2 Instance. Every record is written to an RDS Instance.

Instead of scaling up and handling all the server-stuffs, I would say that using Lambda is the best solution to my current situation. Now, I have read the description and usage for lambda and there is nothing written about using it for Big-Data.

Has anyone experience with it?

Comment: Well, Lambda is what AWS uses for their IoT service - it'll scale to whatever you need.  But make sure you check out the [Lambda Pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/).  We discovered that for heavy use Lambda was about 10X the cost of a decent EC2 instance.  For moderate use Lambda's are great but you've got about 1.5 requests/second - not sure how expensive that'll be.

Comment: Thank you!
I think I will give it a try.

Comment: VanillaBoy, how was your experience with AWS Lambda? I definitely agree here with @stdunbar, Lambda is too pricey for IoT in comparison to EC2.

Comment: Hello Defiozo, I've stayed by an EC2 Instance to handle all the requests and optimzed my clients and server for maximum performance at low costs without using aws lambda services